# How to print " in printf("something equal "x(as char)" ")

Tags: c, printf

How to print `"` in `printf("something equal "x(as char)" ")` ??

Comment: I don't understand much of this question I must say. `puts("\" in printf(\"something equal \"x(as char)\" \")");` would print `" in printf("something equal "x(as char)" ")` but I assume that's not what you actually want. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This is basic C course stuff. A standard subject in the *strings* topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main(void) {
    printf("something equal \"x(as char)\" ");
    return 0;
}
```

In C, the escape character is `\`.
So to print a literal `"`, instead of using it to end a string, use `\"`.

Comment: thanks a lot, i feel real support